# Spring MVC Validation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have a Spring controller that accepts one of my business objects as an argument, that spring is automatically building from form data. One of the attributes of the object is an enum that comes from a select dropdown in the form. I am also using the @Valid notation to do validation on the object, using an implementation of the Spring Validator interface.

In testing, I manually added a selection to the dropdown (using the browser inspector) that is not valid, since it can't be converted to an enum. I would have thought that Spring would just leave the enum attribute as null, and the validator would catch the error, but I actually get a runtime error:

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert CC of type class java.lang.String to class com.app.enums.States
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more details on what you want to happen when this occurs. You could tell Spring how to convert that `String` into an instance of `States` by using a `Converter` (see [this page](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/type-conversion-in-spring-2.html) for details).

Comment: I have a page that handles 500 errors, so the application doesn't necessarily crash hard, they just get my 500 page. So I guess it's really an implementation decision I have to make, would it be worth creating a converter just to handle this use case.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to happen.